# Abrir modal bootstrap con JavaScript o JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

Buenas tardes: Tengo un modal de bootstrap en un formulario llamado `clave_admin.php`, necesito abrir este modal muchas veces y no quiero tener que "incrustar la plantilla" o utilizar `include_once` en cada formulario donde se necesite.

Ya intenté por medio de JQuery con la instrucción `$('#mimodal).modal({show: true});` y no lo abre ni da mensaje de error.

¿Será que no se puede abrir de la forma que planteo?

Comment: puedes revisar la consola del navegador, para verificar si salto algún mensaje de error.

Comment: Sí DavElsanto, ya lo hice y  tampoco muestra mensaje de error en la consola

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar tu modal en jquery deberías hacerlo así:

```
$('#mimodal').modal('show');
```

Saludos!

Comment: Hola Nicolas: Ya lo intenté de la forma que me indicas y no lo abre

Comment: Es que el include lo tenés que hacer si o sí, sino incluís ese modal en tu html no tiene forma de levantarlo. Después con jquery lo mostrás (show) o lo escondes (hide). Saludoss

Comment: Eso es precisamente lo que estoy evitando, son 45 módulos los que necesitan mostrar ese modal para autenticación de clave de administrador.  
Es lamentable que tenga que realizar el include en cada uno de ellos en lugar de llamarlo cada vez que lo necesite.  
Por lo visto no se puede hacer de la forma que lo necesito.  
Muchas Gracias!!!!